# VB.Net DateTimePicker edit calendar portion

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I am trying to use a date time picker to get a month and year from the user (no date). I have the text box portion of the control set correctly but I was wondering if there is a way for me to edit the calendar control so that it only allows selection of months and years or if I can remove that calendar control all together? I have searched for a while but found nothing addressing my question, everything I found refers to the text box portion of the control.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you are okay with just using textbox validation then, since you're up for removing the control altogether?

Comment: No not really, I guess that means I have to keep it... I guess it would be better for me to use separate drop down controls to retrieve the Month and Year and then combine them myself.

Comment: You said you were willing above: "if I can remove that calendar control all together"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

The CustomFormat property looks like you should be able to handle that in the control.

Comment: If you find answers useful (and/or acceptable), don't forget to give it an up-arrow as well. =) 

Happy to help!